# convert pandas pivot with filter to polars efficiently

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

How to convert the below pandas code to polars efficiently. The df given below is a sample df. The original df is much larger in size with more than 5M rows of data. I created a pivot df from polars but not sure how to filter it to get the desired data as shown in pandas df_final df.

```
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
    'col2': ['test1', 'test1', 'test1', 'test1', 'test2', 'test2', 'test2',
             'test2', 'test3', 'test3', 'test3', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5',
             'test1', 'test1', 'test1', 'test3', 'test4'],
    'col3': ['t1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1',
             't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1','tl','tl','tl'],
    'col4': ['input1', 'input2', 'input3', 'input4', 'input1', 'input2',
             'input3', 'input4', 'input1', 'input2', 'input3', 'input5',
             'input2', 'input6', 'input1', 'input1', 'input2', 'input2',
             'input2'],
    'col5': ['result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4', 'result1', 'result2',
             'result3', 'result4', 'result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4',
             'result2', 'result1', 'result2', 'result6', 'result1', 'result1', 'result1'],
    'col6': [10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 50, 20, 100, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20],
    'col7': [100.2, 101.2, 102.3, 101.4, 100.0, 103.0, 104.0, 105.0, 102.0,
             87.0, 107.0, 110.2, 120.0, 88.0, 106.2, 101.1, 100, 90.2, 110]
})

p_df = df.pivot_table(values='col7', index=['col4', 'col5', 'col6'], columns=['col2'], aggfunc='max')
df_final = p_df[((p_df.groupby(level=0).rank(ascending=False) == 1.).any(axis=1))&(p_df>100).any(axis=1)]
print(df_final)

# Start of polars code
df_p = pl.from_pandas(df)

# Group by columns
p_df = df_p.pivot(index=['col4', 'col5', 'col6'], columns='col2', values='col7')
```

Any input is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you say in words what the filter does? It looks like it's: keep row if *"any column is the minimum value per group" AND "any column has a value greater than 100"*?

Comment: it keeps the values per group even if doesn't meet the criteria provided any column has a value greater than 100

Comment: It sounds like the filter `(p_df>100).any(axis=1)` is not necessary then, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series("col1", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], dtype=pl.Int64),
        pl.Series("col2", ['test1', 'test1', 'test1', 'test1', 'test2', 'test2', 'test2', 'test2', 'test3', 'test3', 'test3', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test1', 'test1'], dtype=pl.Utf8),
        pl.Series("col3", ['t1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1'], dtype=pl.Utf8),
        pl.Series("col4", ['input1', 'input2', 'input3', 'input4', 'input1', 'input2', 'input3', 'input4', 'input1', 'input2', 'input3', 'input5', 'input2', 'input6', 'input1', 'input1'], dtype=pl.Utf8),
        pl.Series("col5", ['result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4', 'result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4', 'result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4', 'result2', 'result1', 'result2', 'result6'], dtype=pl.Utf8),
        pl.Series("col6", [10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 50, 20, 100, 10, 10], dtype=pl.Int64),
        pl.Series("col7", [100.2, 101.2, 102.3, 101.4, 100.0, 103.0, 104.0, 105.0, 102.0, 87.0, 107.0, 110.2, 120.0, 88.0, 106.2, 101.1], dtype=pl.Float64),
    ]
)
```

#### Pivot then filter

```
(
    df
    .pivot('col7',(idx:=['col4','col5','col6']),'col2','first')
    .filter(
        (pl.any_horizontal(pl.exclude(idx).rank(descending=True).over('col4')==1)) &
        (pl.any_horizontal(pl.col('^test.+$')>100))
        )
    .sort(idx)
)
shape: (6, 8)
┌────────┬─────────┬──────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ col4   ┆ col5    ┆ col6 ┆ test1 ┆ test2 ┆ test3 ┆ test4 ┆ test5 │
│ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ str     ┆ i64  ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64   │
╞════════╪═════════╪══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ input1 ┆ result1 ┆ 10   ┆ 100.2 ┆ 100.0 ┆ 102.0 ┆ null  ┆ null  │
│ input1 ┆ result2 ┆ 10   ┆ 106.2 ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ null  │
│ input2 ┆ result2 ┆ 20   ┆ 101.2 ┆ 103.0 ┆ 87.0  ┆ 120.0 ┆ null  │
│ input3 ┆ result3 ┆ 30   ┆ 102.3 ┆ 104.0 ┆ 107.0 ┆ null  ┆ null  │
│ input4 ┆ result4 ┆ 40   ┆ 101.4 ┆ 105.0 ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ null  │
│ input5 ┆ result4 ┆ 50   ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ 110.2 ┆ null  ┆ null  │
└────────┴─────────┴──────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

In this example `pl.exclude(idx)` and `pl.col('^test.+$')` represent the same thing (and are interchangeable), I just put both to show that there are (at least) two ways to refer to those columns.

#### Filter then pivot

If for some reason you wanted to filter before the pivot, you could do that with window functions

```
(
    df
    .with_columns(zz=(pl.col('col7').rank(descending=True)).over('col4','col2'))
    .filter(
        (pl.col('zz')==1).over((idx:=['col4','col5','col6']),mapping_strategy='join').list.any(),
        (pl.col('col7')>100).over(idx,mapping_strategy='join').list.any()
    )
    .pivot('col7',idx,'col2','first')
    .sort(idx)
)
shape: (6, 7)
┌────────┬─────────┬──────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ col4   ┆ col5    ┆ col6 ┆ test1 ┆ test2 ┆ test3 ┆ test4 │
│ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ str     ┆ i64  ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64   │
╞════════╪═════════╪══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ input1 ┆ result1 ┆ 10   ┆ 100.2 ┆ 100.0 ┆ 102.0 ┆ null  │
│ input1 ┆ result2 ┆ 10   ┆ 106.2 ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ null  │
│ input2 ┆ result2 ┆ 20   ┆ 101.2 ┆ 103.0 ┆ 87.0  ┆ 120.0 │
│ input3 ┆ result3 ┆ 30   ┆ 102.3 ┆ 104.0 ┆ 107.0 ┆ null  │
│ input4 ┆ result4 ┆ 40   ┆ 101.4 ┆ 105.0 ┆ null  ┆ null  │
│ input5 ┆ result4 ┆ 50   ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ 110.2 ┆ null  │
└────────┴─────────┴──────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

By prefiltering, it removes the test5 column since it's otherwise all null.

##### Response to comment

I think what you want is this:

```
(
    df
    .pivot('col7',(idx:=['col4','col5','col6']),'col2','first')
    .filter(pl.any_horizontal(
        (pl.col('^test.+$').rank(descending=True).over('col4')==1) &
        (pl.col('^test.+$')>100)
        ))
    .sort(idx)
)
shape: (6, 8)
┌────────┬─────────┬──────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ col4   ┆ col5    ┆ col6 ┆ test1 ┆ test2 ┆ test3 ┆ test4 ┆ test5 │
│ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ str     ┆ i64  ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64   │
╞════════╪═════════╪══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ input1 ┆ result1 ┆ 10   ┆ 100.2 ┆ 100.0 ┆ 102.0 ┆ null  ┆ null  │
│ input1 ┆ result2 ┆ 10   ┆ 106.2 ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ null  │
│ input2 ┆ result2 ┆ 20   ┆ 101.2 ┆ 103.0 ┆ 87.0  ┆ 120.0 ┆ null  │
│ input3 ┆ result3 ┆ 30   ┆ 102.3 ┆ 104.0 ┆ 107.0 ┆ null  ┆ null  │
│ input4 ┆ result4 ┆ 40   ┆ 101.4 ┆ 105.0 ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ null  │
│ input5 ┆ result4 ┆ 50   ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ 110.2 ┆ null  ┆ null  │
└────────┴─────────┴──────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. One quick question, if the 'col7' values are a string like "100.2 %\n(test)" and i want to filter it based upon the values before the %, and in this case it would be 100.2, how one would be able to achieve it? I tried to split the col and then compare it to a value, but getting error

Comment: something like `pl.col('col7').str.extract("(\d+\.?\d+)").cast(pl.Float64)`

Comment: or with splitting on the % then `pl.col('col7').str.split('%').list.first().str.strip_chars().cast(pl.Float64)`

Comment: When i ran the code on a full data set, I encountered a situation. The pivoted table is showing a row, where the column values are not the highest for the columns which met the filtering but the data value was highest in one of the columns which was below my filtering threshold. Is there a way to drop that data. I updated the original df data in the post to include such a scenario. the df would now lead to show data for "input2 result1 20    100.0    NaN   90.2  110.0    NaN" bus column data 100.0 & 110.0 are not the highest in those columns but 90.2 is highest but below 100.

Comment: The first filter keeps rows where it keeps a row where any of the columns is the highest for its `col4` based group, the second filter says that at least one column has to have a value over 100. The two filters both have to be met but they don't have to be met by the same column. It seems like what you're saying is that it doesn't count if a column is the highest if it isn't over 100? Do I have that right?

Comment: That's correct. The above code works as intended. You are spot on with it. Can this also be achieved with filter first and then pivot or it can only be done with Pivot and filtering? The reason I was asking is that, I read in one of the articles, that pivot can sometimes be slow with a large dataset which i am not sure if that's the case or not. Thanks again.